# Importing mysql data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

It's very simple to someone but looks like complicated to me. I have 2 tables, one is called jos_users other is called jvdb_users. Tables are exact same, both containing user informations such as user email, password, name, etc. Only table one have many users, table two is empty, i need to transfer all fields and data from table one to table two. How do i do that with phpmyadmin and mysql on linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (SELECT * FROM table2);
```

Comment: I didn't saw that there was one field more in table 2 so i had to list fields instead to select all. but basically i used function like you sugested.

Answer (score 12):

if they both have the same columns you can use this command

```
INSERT INTO `tabletwo` (SELECT * FROM tableone)
```

You can write this in the SQL section of phpmyadmin

Comment: Alternatively, if you go to the "Operations" tab of the table you want to copy, there is a GUI that allows you to copy data from one table to another. It uses the same SQL statement that you wrote.